# Best method to get url from notification and load into Fragment's webview?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

So basically im just new to Android, and im making a application which sends realtime notifications sended with php from server.

Now i want that the notification when clicked by the user opens a webpage in my webview.
Its a webbased app.

Im using 3 tabs to switch between 3 fragents.
Each fragment got a different webview.

Now this is mine GCMintentService.java:

```
   package blah.blah;


import static blah.blah.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;

import static blah.blah.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;
import blah.blah.R;
import blah.blah.R.drawable;
import blah.blah.R.string;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Toestel geregistreerd: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Je toestel is geregistreerd");
        Log.d("NAME", NotificationMain.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, NotificationMain.name, NotificationMain.klas, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Toestel nog niet geregistreerd!");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Ontvangen bericht");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyFragment.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

A main activity holds the 3 fragments with all differnt webviews.
I get the urls from a array called in FragmentAdapter.java where it extends FragmentAdapter.

Works perfect... here
is the fragmentAdapter:

```
    package blah.blah;

import blah.blah.MyFragment;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


    String[] toVisit={
        "www.google.com",
        "www.stackoverlow.com",
        "www.lorumipsum.com",
        };

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // Here is where all the magic of the adapter happens
        // As you can see, this is really simple.
        return MyFragment.newInstance(toVisit[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {        
        if(position == 0)
        {
            return "Klassen";
        }
        else if(position == 1)
        {
            return "Docenten";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Lokalen";
        }   
    }   
}
```

But how to load differnt urls depending on the retrieved info from the server? ,
The GCM push is sended with php with the usually code.

Should be something with intent.PushExtra("google.com, http://google.com") // for example
all doesn't work. I hope my question is clear.

All help is appriciated!
Just share all ur tips & thoughts:P.

Oh ye and my MyFragment.java if its usefull:

```
    package blah.blah;


import blah.blah.R;
import blah.blah.R.id;
import blah.blah.R.layout;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    WebView browser; 
    String url;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;
    Intent extras = getActivity().getIntent();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.myfragment_layout, 
            container, 
            false);

        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        browser=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/geeninternet.html");

            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void onProgressChanged(final WebView view, final int progress)   
            {
                if(progress == 100)
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
        });

        browser.loadUrl(url); 

        // Just load whatever URL this fragment is
        // created with.
        return view;
    }
    // This is the method the pager adapter will use
    // to create a new fragment
    public static Fragment newInstance(String url)
    {
        MyFragment f=new MyFragment();
        f.url=url;
        return f;
    }
    // Met browser;
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
        browser.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sla webview op
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        browser.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }

    /**
     * Herstel staat van webview
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (webViewBundle != null)
        {
            browser.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Ontvangen bericht");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

In this code you take only one value from the notification payload - the value of the `price` key.

You didn't include the server code, so I don't know if you are sending a URL with the notification. If you do, you should get its value from the `intent` in the `onMessage` method and pass it to the code that open the web-view. If you don't, you should change your server code to include the URL in the notification payload.

EDIT :

In order to pass the URL to your fragment :

1. Get the URL from the extras of the intent in `onMessage()`.
2. Pass it to `generateNotification`.
3. Add the URL as an extra to the intent that would start the activity when the notification is tapped : `notificationIntent.putExtra ("url",url)`.
4. In the fragment, in the code where you initialize the web-view, get the URL from the extras of the intent that started the activity that contains the fragment (`getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"`).

EDIT2:

1. You should load the web-view in `onActivityCreated()`, not in `onCreateView()`. `onCreateView()` is called before the activity is created, so `getActivity()` will return null.
2. Don't use that code as is : `String test = (getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"));` Make sure that `getActivity()` doesn't return null. I believe that when the `getActivity()` is not null, you can assume that `getIntent()` and `getExtras()` won't return null, but it's safer to check. `getString("url")` will return null if the activity wasn't opened from a notification. Therefore you should make sure that it has a value before loading the web-view.
3. There may be a problem with the notification flags :

> ```
> // set intent so it does not start a new activity
> notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
>         Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
> ```

It seems that the notification won't open a new activity if such an activity already exists (for example, if the app is already running). In that case, your fragment code for `onCreateView()` and `onActivityCreated()` won't be called and the URL won't be loaded. You should either change the flags so that a new activity will always be created, or you should put the logic that loads the web-view as a result of the notification somewhere else - probably in `onResume()`.

Comment: Thnx for ur answer! I try it in a few min:) Im pretty new to java so i used this base: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ i use this method to send the data to the desired devices, i just edited but its the same system.

Comment: I can succesfully get the url from the server; which i can recieve with java:

Comment: Check my edited answer ( I delete it in a few mins, but otherwise i can't add code on a proper way.. ),............I added the edited code now to my question. Thnx for the tip.

Comment: Im really sorry, but i just can't get it.... It just doesn't notice the putExtra..., Im completely not familiar with this, so i would really appriciate if i could get 10mins of ur time and u could edit myFragment.java to a example which is useable for me, If i load the app myself i get a nullpointer exception, and if i load it from notification it just takes mainactivity.java.....

Comment: Is MainActivity the activity that contains your fragments?

Comment: Im using a view pager to switch between three fragments. Each loads a webview, The 3 urls for the different webviews are defined in a array in a extends FragmentPagerAdapter, The MainActivity.java where i define this is a extends FragmentActivity. Than we got a normal extends fragment file which is myFragment.java, which generates the webviews by the urls defined in FragmentPagerAdapter. I hope u understand this build:P (Im sure u will, but idk if i explained it well).

Comment: In MyFragment you have a member called extras that you init with getActivity().getIntent() before the activity is create.  This causes null pointer exception. You should remove that line.

Comment: So basically i should use this? getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("url"); or getActivity().getIntent().getString("url"), (Which makes a error). Really sorry if i ask stupid questions, but im not that familiar with android. Ur so kind and u have so much patience:P And its unlikely it would still work when i click a notification and it would load the desired webpage, if i delete extra.

Comment: No, it's getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("url")

Comment: My comments about the extras variable refers to the original version of MyFragment class that you posted.  Perhaps you already removed that line.

Comment: But what u ment than? When i removed GetExtra, it didn't crash when i opened the app. Though it still didn't load the desired webpage getted from intent. (Logically) ,,,, in above comment reaction, could u edit the MyFragemnt.java of above a bit so i get a bit the thoughts on how to do it?:P

Comment: I meant you should remove this line : `Intent extras = getActivity().getIntent();` if you haven't already. Don't remove the code I asked you to add in my answer. And it would help if you post the current version of MyFragment.java and remove the old versions from the question.

Comment: Updated lowest code tag in my question, which contains the MyFragment.java, I got no idea if i did it like u described... But if i remove the getExtra there is no NullPointerException so it just doesn't get anything and runs well, but maybe i just ruined it in my myfragment.java:p

Comment: Have you tried to move the `browser.loadUrl(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"));` line to `onResume()`?

Comment: No.... public void onResume()
    {
     browser.loadUrl(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"));
    }, I updated the GCMIntentService.java in my question aswell, maybe it doesn't send the url at all... but i don't think so, i know i get the url, and i did exactly what u said, and its logically all right. But wherever i put the getExtras() etc. The app crashes with nullponter, so probably in the GCMIntent is something wrong.

Comment: Which method call returns null? getActivity(), getIntent(), getExtras() or getString?

Comment: GetExtras(), For example if i do getActivity().getIntent().getString("url")); it displays the app corretly. (Just doesn't load the desired url when i click the notification). So i assume its getExtras(). ---- Anyways im going to get some sleep, i want to thank u again for ur afford, and i look tomorrow further into it. It would be nice if u got some nice ideas left u could post here:P And maybe ur also back tomorrow, and we look furtheri n this problem if u want.

Comment: And does `getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("url")` return null too?

Comment: No this does just run the app, but doesn't get the extra value from the notification. Is it maybe becouse intent to mainactivit.class, and the webview gets generated in MyFragment.java. Idk if this does really matther alot?

Comment: I Finally got it to work!:) Thnx so much for ur help and patience.